# Allow Line-Breaks in Vaadin Flow Tooltips

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Line-Breaks and Vaadin Flow Tooltips are discussed publicly, still a recommended solution is missing (e.g. https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17952864/tooltip-with-line-break-in-vaadin; concluding in "this does not work")

The official documentation on the tooltip component does not contain any hint.

Are there any suggestions or known workarounds?

Cheers for any help on that requirement,
Daniel

I also experimented a bit with vaadin 23 on tooltips.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zRhI.png)

None of the promising approaches did work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pm6s.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 7):

It's semi supported by adding the following to your styles.css and using \n as new line character.

```
vaadin-tooltip-overlay::part(content) {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: Indeed - this is the "official" working Solution with Vaadin 23. Cheers!!

Comment: In V24 `white-space: pre-line;` worked better for me.

Comment: Don't you have issues with extra newline and spaces, caused by the pretty-printing of the web component source code? We struggle to remove the extra newline at the start of the tooltip, `white-space: pre-line;` works around the indentation spaces before the slot.